# Resultados das requisições desordenados

Tags: php, ajax, libcurl

Tenho 1 textarea com varias linhas, a cada linha desse textarea tenho dados para efetuar uma requisição post em uma unica url, ele checa cada linha e me manda o resultado na tela via jquery, o problema e que os resultados que sao printados na tela não estam ordenados conforme os dados colocados no textarea, devia imprimir os resultados em forma de lista das linhas 1, 2, 3, 4 do textarea em sequencia, porem ele printa isso desordenadamente 4, 2, 1, 3 ele checa se um proxy e a porta funcionam exemplo 292.168.391.34|8080  e feita a requisição em uma pagina colocando os dados antes do separador | no input do proxy e apos o separador em outro input da porta, e com preg_match capturo a mensagem de conectado e com um if faço printar na tela a mensagem se foi bem sucedido ou nao juntamente ao lado da liinha testada, mais sempre os resultados voltam desordenados não batendo conforme a sequecia no textarea como resolvo isso  ?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa observar que o ajax é assíncrono então ele pode te dar a resposta de uma requisição que foi feita depois antes de uma que foi feita antes. Então para resolver isso você poderia fazer a primeira requisição e depois na função de callback dessa realizar a outra e assim por diante, na ordem que voce precisa. Não sei a sintaxe do jquery mas vai um exemplo:

```
function callback2 () {
    ajax3(callback3);
}
function callback1 () {
    ajax2(callback2);
}
ajax1(callback1);
```